# Two pictures in one background

Tags: typography, backgrounds, watermark

I have a document that has only one page(in pdf). How can I to have a background as watermark with two(or multiple) pictures on this page(as a watermark)?

Comment: The package [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) is suitable. You will find a lot of examples here.

Comment: I didn't find anything in background package about it.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will get you started.

First, compile the image file `circle.tex`

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=blue!20] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the image file `triangle.tex`

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=green!20] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Next, you have to compile the following file twice for the watermark to show up at the right place:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1,
  angle=0,
  contents={
    \includegraphics{circle}
    \includegraphics{triangle}
}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: the pictures do not layout with transparency as watermark on printed page. Why???

Comment: What do you mean? The output shown in my answer has the circle and triangle as transparent. Do you mean that when you compile the document using `pdflatex` you do not get the output shown in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

The following example uses the eso-pic package to put two pictures as background for the first page of the document:

```
%---------------------------
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,pagesize]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx,eso-pic,picture}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \put(.5\textwidth,.5\textheight){%
    \includegraphics{knuth.jpg}%
  }
  \put(5cm,18cm){%
    \includegraphics{knuth.jpg}%
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \blindtext[6]
\end{document}
%---------------------------
```

...Rolf