# Composite images inside a figure in LaTeX?

Tags: graphics, floats

I would like to have a figure that overlays a transparent png on top of a pdf. What is the best way to composite images inside a LaTeX figure? I would like to avoid compositing these images using separate image editing software beforehand, if possible.

Comment: Would this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151124/34618

Comment: The `stackengine` package provides `\stackinset{l,c,r}{h-offset}{t,c,b}{v-offset}{inset image}{base image}` to allow relative placement of the inset to be configured.  The `l,c,r` is either left, center or right alignment, while `t,c,b` is either top, center, or bottom alignment.  The offsets move the inset relative to the alignment.

Comment: Could http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34921/ be of help?

Answer (score 2):

According to Section 12 in [Using Imported Graphics in Latex and pdfLatex](ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/info/epslatex.pdf) by Keith Reckdahl, 2006:

```
\makebox[0pt][l]{\includegraphics{firstgraphic}}%
\includegraphics{secondgraphic}
```